# Set default tab with PagerSlidingTabStrip Library

Tags: android, android-tabs, material-design, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am using this library: [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

I know that I can change the default tab using `pager.setCurrentItem(1);` but the first swipe works bad, it suffers a jerk (because the tabs are centered at start). Really I can't explain better in english, sorry.

The other methods that I have found is about ActionBar, and I can't use them with the toolbar.

Can I set the default tab using other method? If you compile the app and use `pager.setCurrentItem(1);` you can see that I want to say.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: post your code where you inialize the viewpager please.. and btw whatever you did with actionbar you do with toolbar like getSupportActionBar();

Comment: My app is a clone of the sample app inside that github repository. You can see all the code there.